# Regex Search Help

Tags: php, regex, arrays

Given a string such as:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}
```

I want to find every integer within quotes and create an array of all integers found in the string.

End result should be an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

I'm guessing you use preg_match() but I have no experience with regular expressions :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
 $str = 'a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}';
 print_r(array_values(unserialize($str)));
```

Not a regex, same answer.

This works because the string you have is a serialized PHP array. Using a regex would be the wrong way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The regex (in a program) would look like this:

```
$str = 'a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}';
preg_match_all('/"(\d+)"/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```